# Two tube coil components

Tags: components, identification

What are these components? They have lots of wiring.

The left (bigger) one has 2 pins and description

00846
R647 Y

The right (smaller) one has also 2 pins and description

94565
R652

What kind of components are these?

[image]

Possibly similar function component with 1R0 at the top (updated after the answer of Bimpelrekkie):

[image]

Comment: They are inductors with a ferrite core. I suggest that you buy a cheap Chinese component tester, like: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/LCR-T4-Mega328-Transistor-Tester-Diode-Triode-Capacitance-ESR-Meter-MOS-NPN-QE-/202034835964?hash=item2f0a36f1fc:g:oNIAAOSwcXpZn~TV  then you can just plug in the component, see what it is and have an indication of its value.

Comment: Thanks ... and good idea about such a tester ... I just couldn't recognize what it is and couldn't find the numbers by googling (please make it an answer).

Comment: The ferrite coil on the right *might* be magnetically biased. It appears to have a separate ferrite part between coil (which is wound on a ferrite "dumbell") and plastic base. Test it with a steel probe - like a screwdriver to see if it attracts. The ferrite part at the base *may* be a ceramic magnet.

Comment: glen_geek .. they are both magnetic (both top from the left and right inductor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are inductors with a ferrite core.

I do not expect that the numbers will give you any information, these inductors are often not standard components but custom made for the manufacturer of the product in which they're used. So probably those numbers are just internal part numbers and meaningless for us.

These are unshielded so the magnetic field can "escape" or you could use these to pick-up some magnetic field.

In a shielded inductor you usually do not see the wires:

[image]

Comment: Ah, I found more of these, like a square version of 1R0 (I will add a picture), they came from an old VGA card. Are those 1R0 similar with the big ones from my initial question?

Comment: Yes, that "1R0" marked component is also an inductor, but not how the magnetic core forms a loop (2 loops actually, like a figure 8) so the magnetic field cannot escape so easily making it more or less shielded.